# how to store multiple values from listview column to a single entry to database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview

i need to store values of multiple column  from listview to a single entry to my database..
example

```
ID    |  Description  |  Price
1     |  Big          |  20
2     |  Large        |  40
3     |  Small        |  60
```

i want to store the values (Big, Large, Small) to a separate table

```
ID    |  Description        | Price
1     |  Big, Large, Small  | 120

ive tried using 
foreach (ListView s in ????? )
{
}
```

please help me... :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foreach you can use following code.

```
class Product
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int Price { get; set; }
        }
```

Assign test data to list

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>() { 
                new Product() { ID = 1, Description = "BBB" , Price = 10},
                new Product() { ID = 2, Description = "CCC" , Price = 40},
                new Product() { ID = 3, Description = "DDD" , Price = 60}};
            List<Product> newList = new List<Product>();
            newList.Add(new Product() { ID = list[0].ID ,  Description = string.Join(", ", list.Select(a => a.Description).ToArray()), 
                Price = list.Select(a => a.Price).Sum()});
```

Also if you want to get value from ListView you can use following code.

```
var p = new Product()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32((ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("lblID") as Label).Text),
                            Description = string.Join(", ", (ListView1.Items.Select(a => (a.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label).Text)).ToArray()),
                            Price = ListView1.Items.Select(a => Convert.ToInt32((a.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text)).Sum()
                    };
```

And also you have to replace "lblID" with your label.

Comment: i want to get the values from ListView.. how can i do that? the values is already displayed to ListView... :)